# cannot read bytes from file with go after writing

Tags: python, go, io, byte

So, i am trying to make a simple AOT virtual machine in golang, that reads a bytecode file as it's input. I am trying to very basically, write bytes to a file then read them with `ioutil`, however I am encountering a null dereference error.

This is my python code used for writing to the file:

```
btest = open("test.thief", "w")
bytes_to_write = bytearray([1, 44, 56, 55, 55, 0])

btest.write(bytes_to_write)

btest.close()
```

This is the code in my go file that I am using to read the bytes

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "io/ioutil"
   "os"
)

func main() {
  //gets command line args
    userArgs := os.Args[1:]

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(userArgs[0]) // just pass the file name
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

     fmt.Println(bytes)
     machine := NewEnv()
     ReadBytes(machine, bytes)

}
```

And this is the error i am getting:

```
Joshuas-MacBook-Pro-3:thief Josh$ ./bin/Thief test.thief
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x2af3]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.ReadBytes(0xc82000e390, 0xc82000c480, 0x6, 0x206)
    /Users/Josh/thief/src/Thief/read.go:26 +0x353
main.main()
    /Users/Josh/thief/src/Thief/Main.go:18 +0x1f2
```

I have also tried opening the file in binary mode with the python code, but it produces the same error. Basically the goal of this is that I want to be able to extract an array of bytes but also have a way to write theme.

Am i writing the bytes incorrectly?

Here is the hexdump:

`012c 3837 3700`

EDIT:

This is the rest of my go files

opfuncs.go

```
package main


//file for machine functions and operations

//prints string format of some bytes
func print(env Env, data []byte) {
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}


var OPERS map[byte]func(Env, []byte)

//0 is reserved as the null terminator
func init(){
    OPERS = map[byte]func(Env, []byte){
        1:print,
    }
}
```

env.go

```
package main


//file for the env struct



type Env struct {
    items map[string]interface{}
}

func NewEnv() Env {
    return Env{make(map[string]interface{})}
}

//general getter
func (self *Env) get(key string) interface{} {
    val, has := self.items[key]
    if has {
        return val
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

//general setter
func (self *Env) set(key string, value interface{}) {
    self.items[key] = value
}

func (self *Env) contains(key string) bool {
    _, has := self.items[key]
    return has
}

func (self *Env) declare(key string) {
    self.items[key] = Null{}
}

func (self *Env) is_null(key string) bool {
    _, ok := self.items[key].(Null)
    return ok
}

//deletes an item from storage
func (self *Env) del(key string) {
    delete(self.items, key)
}
```

read.go

```
package main

//file that contains the reading function for the VM

func ReadBytes(env Env, in []byte) {
    bytes := make([]byte, 1)
    fn := byte(0)
    mode := 0
    for i:=0;i<len(in);i++ {
        switch mode {
        case 0:
            fn = byte(i)
            mode = 1
        case 1:
            if i != len(in)-1 {
                if in[i+1] == 0 {
                    bytes = append(bytes, in[i])
                    mode = 2
                } else {
                    bytes = append(bytes, in[i])
                }
            } else {
                bytes = append(bytes, in[i])
            }
        case 2:
            OPERS[fn](env, bytes)
            mode = 0
            fn = byte(0)
            bytes = make([]byte, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you hexdump the file to see the contents?

Comment: `012c 3837 3700 `

Comment: thats the hexdump

Comment: can you put your complete golang code and give a permalink in the question - https://play.golang.org/ (with the Share link)

Comment: with the given code. I get it perfectly fine

> go run test.go test.thief
[1 44 56 55 55 0]

Comment: yes i actually tested the single file and its likely a something else going wrong

Comment: How do i put a whole go package in the playground? this is my repo https://github.com/jweinst1/thief

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Python 3, the file must be opened in the binary mode:

```
btest = open("test.thief", "wb")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not writing to the file in your python code?

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytearray
```

After your third line which would explain why golang can't find the file contents.

Also you're not using `bytes` so your gocode won't compile. Do this instead.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "io/ioutil"
   "os"
)

func main() {
  //gets command line args
    userArgs := os.Args[1:]

    _, err := ioutil.ReadFile(userArgs[0]) // just pass the file name
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: Im on python3, maybe thats why? I am using bytes in some other code but its not causing the error and isn't relevant so i removed it.

Comment: This is the hexdump of the file

Comment: `012c 3837 3700 `

Comment: I don't see how the contents of the file matter unless thats some golf code that interacts with go's `ReadFile` or something.

Comment: well this code works if i read some normal file like a .txt file or something, so i feel i might be writing the bytes in correctly.

Comment: the contents of the gocode above will not compile with go's regular compiler because the variable `bytes` is declared and not used. Did you write your own go compiler?